# EntityFramework with generics

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

In my project I often need to return a `List<T>`, something like this:

```
MyDbEntities context = new MyDbEntities():
List<Employees> myList= context.Employees.ToList();
return myList;
```

Is there a way to do that with generics? Creating only one function that returns different types of list, based on what it was called on.

Comment: Yes, it's. You have to add static class and create method to return list of any type of entity.

Comment: No need for a separate (extension) method, just call `context.Set<SomeType>()`. About as concise as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Factory method design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method) ( creational design pattern that provides an interface for creating objects in a superclass, but allows subclasses to alter the type of objects that will be created), or for your case Create extension method in static class:

```
public static class MyDbContextExtensions
{
    public static List<T> Get<T>(this MyDbEntities dbEtities) where T: class
    {
        return dbEtities.Set<T>().ToList();
    }
}
```

and you may use like this:

```
var context = new MyDbEntities():
var myList= context.Get<Employees>();
return myList;
```

Comment: May as well call `context.Set<Employees>();` directly, don't you think?

Comment: Honestly I don't see any much difference between  context.Get<Employees>() and context.Employees.ToList(). Maybe somebody can explain me what it gains?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

```cs
public static List<TEntity> GetList<TEntity>(DbContext context) 
    where TEntity: class
{
    return context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
}
```

Comment: May as well call `context.Set<SomeType>();` directly, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will be shorter, since you are always using MyDbEntities (some credits to  @SvyatoslavDanyliv)

```
public static List<TEntity> GetList<TEntity>(DbContext context = null) 
    where TEntity: class
{
    if(context==null) context = new MyDbEntities():
    return context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
}
```

you can use it like this

```
return GetList<Employees>();
```

or if you have dbcontext already

```
return GetList<Employees>(_context);

// although it is the same
return _context.Set<Employees>().ToList();
```